# How can I create a buffer suitable for dynamic updates in SharpDX?

Tags: sharpdx

I want to set a buffer that is updated every frame but can't figure it out, what i have to do.

The only working thing i have is this:

```
mdexcription = new BufferDescription(Matrix.SizeInBytes * Matrices.Length, ResourceUsage.Dynamic, BindFlags.VertexBuffer, CpuAccessFlags.Write, ResourceOptionFlags.None, 0);
instanceBuffer = SharpDX.Direct3D11.Buffer.Create(Device, Matrices, mdexcription);

vBB = new VertexBufferBinding(instanceBuffer, Matrix.SizeInBytes, 0);
DeviceContext.InputAssembler.SetVertexBuffers(1, vBB);
```

Draw:

```
//Change Matrices (Matrix[]) every frame...
instanceBuffer.Dispose();
instanceBuffer = SharpDX.Direct3D11.Buffer.Create(Device, Matrices, mdexcription);

vBB = new VertexBufferBinding(instanceBuffer, Matrix.SizeInBytes, 0);
DeviceContext.InputAssembler.SetVertexBuffers(1, vBB);
```

I guess Dispose() and creating a new buffer is slow and can be done much faster.

I've read about DataStream but i do not know, how to set this up properly.

What steps do i have to do to set up a DataStream to achieve fast every-frame update?

---

Edit:

Finally got it. I used that:

```
mdescription = new BufferDescription(Matrix.SizeInBytes * Matrices.Length, ResourceUsage.Dynamic, BindFlags.VertexBuffer, CpuAccessFlags.Write, ResourceOptionFlags.None, 0);
instanceBuffer = SharpDX.Direct3D11.Buffer.Create(Device, Matrices, mdescription);

vBB = new VertexBufferBinding(instanceBuffer, Matrix.SizeInBytes, 0);
DeviceContext.InputAssembler.SetVertexBuffers(instSlot, vBB);
```

Draw:

```
DataStream stream;
var dataBox = DeviceContext.MapSubresource(instanceBuffer, MapMode.WriteDiscard, SharpDX.Direct3D11.MapFlags.None, out stream);
stream.WriteRange(Matrices);
DeviceContext.UnmapSubresource(instanceBuffer, 0); //to update the data on GPU

stream.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two basic ways to update a buffer.

1. Use [`DeviceContext.UpdateSubresource()`](http://sharpdx.org/documentation/api/m-sharpdx-direct3d11-devicecontext-updatesubresource). `source` is your source data, in the form of a `DataBox` (you can pass most value types and arrays as `DataBox`), and `resource` is your vertex buffer.

   This is the easiest way to copy small data in one pass, and I use it mostly for updating constant buffers.

   In your case it could be:

   ```
   DeviceContext.UpdateSubresource(yourMatrixArray, yourVertexBuffer);
   ```
2. Use [`DeviceContext.MapSubresource`](http://sharpdx.org/documentation/api/m-sharpdx-direct3d11-devicecontext-mapsubresource-2). `resource` is your vertex bufffer, `mode` is the way you want to update your data, `flags` are obviously flags, and you get a `DataStream` (inherits from `Stream`) which you can use to copy your data.

   I use this when I'm updating complex data that may have complex structures, like vertex buffers.

   In your case, it could be:

   ```
   DataStream dataStream;

   ImmediateContext.MapSubresource(yourVertexBuffer, MapMode.WriteDiscard, MapFlags.None, out dataStream);

   dataStream.Write(...);
   ```

   Don't forget to unmap the resource when finished.

   ```
   dataStream.Dispose(); // Not 100% sure if necessary
   ImmediateContext.UnmapSubresource(yourVertexBuffer, 0);
   ```

There are lots of other options, like when you're using subresources and stuff. Make sure you read the docs.

Comment: For the specific case of updating a buffer every frame (a buffer declared with ResourceUsage.Dynamic) part **2** of the answer (Map with MapMode.WriteDiscard) should be used. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn508285(v=vs.85).aspx